# How to make the wix database items unique

Tags: javascript, database, velo

In my **Wix** website, I created a database and the field named "**`giaCode`**" should be unique.

The problem is the **Wix** database doesn't have any function to keep the items which are unique - like the foreign key.

So I decided to make a function to search and delete any duplicate items in the database. But it doesn't work.

**The process should be:**

1. *Import the CSV file to the database*
2. *Check all rows and record it's "**_id**" to the array*
3. *call the array to remove the rows*

---

The Wix code (**`data.js`**) is below:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

let n,i,j,duplicateData,items;
let k = 0;

wixData.query("Diamond")
  .count()
  .then( (num) => {
    n = num;
});

wixData.query("Customer")
  .find()
  .then( (data) => {
    items = data.items;
 });

export function checkDuplicates(value, info) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        for (j = 0; i < n; j++) { 
            wixData.query("myCollection")
            .eq("giaCode", items[i].giaCode)
            .find()
            .then ((DupResults) => {
                duplicateData[k][j] = DupResults.items;
                k++;
            });
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) { 
        for (j = 1; j < duplicateData[k][j].giaCode.length; j++) {
            wixData.remove("Diamond", duplicateData[i][j].giaCode)
        }
    }
}


export function Diamond_afterInsert(item, context) {
    checkDuplicates()
}
```

It should be work but I get the error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOEF.jpg)

Comment: Hello @TerryLau ! There's one rule to go by > 

*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*. Once you do, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51934743/edit) accordingly. Thank you! :)

Comment: To be bit more specific, biggest gripe is the '*Verifiable*'  part.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you're doing wrong if I understand you correctly. That is, if you are trying to stop duplicates from being added to the collection.

1. Use a `beforeInsert` hook so the item never gets into the collection instead of deleting it once it is in there already.
2. In your delete, you would have deleted the existing item with the `giaCode` along with the duplicate. I don't think that is what you wanted.
3. You are not call `.eq()` correctly. You aren't saying what value it should be equal to.

Try this instead:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

export function searchForDuplicates(value) {
  return wixData.query("Diamond")
    .eq("giaCode", value)
    .find()
    .then((results) => {
      return results.items.length;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      let errorMsg = err;
    });
}

export function Diamond_beforeInsert(item) {
  return searchForDuplicates(item.giaCode).then((res) => {
    if(res > 0) {   
      return Promise.reject("Duplicate");
    }
    return item;
  });
}
```

I switched it to a `beforeInsert` hook, fixed the `.eq()`, and removed all the unnecessary code.

Comment: I've try the code but it sill get some error message. Same as the **photo**.